# Is there any way to calculate age of a person based on DOB and quarter of the provided year sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have DOB = '01/12/1997'  and Quarter = '2' and Year ='2020'
and I want the list of employee whose age is 50 in 2nd quarter of year
'2020'. How can i get this in SQL server.

ID    Name   DOB
1     John   1982-01-09 00:00:00
2     Sally  1990-05-20 00:00:00
3     Adam   1997-12-01 00:00:00

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in SQL Server or C#? What does your question have to do with ASP.Net?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducable example; there's a lot of different ways of doing this, adding some code to the question gives us a clue as to what the best solution for you may be.

Comment: Is DOB a common abbreviation of Day of Birth? I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `DATЕDD()` and `DATEPART()` is an option:

```
SELECT DOB
FROM (VALUES
   (CONVERT(date, '19971207')),
   (CONVERT(date, '19700607')),
   (CONVERT(date, '19771207')),
   (CONVERT(date, '19971108'))
) d (DOB)
WHERE 
   DATEPART(year, DATEADD(year, 50, DOB)) = 2020 AND
   DATEPART(quarter, DATEADD(year, 50, DOB)) = 2
```

Result:

```
DOB
1970-06-07
```